# jquery click not working with image tag

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

Here is the generate markup. I need this data-target attribute on each `<img/>` tag. I can do without it. But I don't think that is causing this problem because this thing worked fine before.

```html
<ul>
<li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail item">
            <div class="image"><img src="http://dummy_link/" alt=""></div>
            <div class="info">
                <a href="http://dummy_link/" target="_blank">
                <div class="sub-title">Va</div></a>
                <hr class="divider">
                <div class="cost">365</div>
                <img alt="click_here" onclick="$.hanger_click_handler()" class="span2 pull-right logo-right visible-desktop visible-tablet hang" src="/static/img/hanger.svg" data-target="http://dummy_link/">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail item">
            <div class="image"><img src="http://dummy_link/" alt=""></div>
            <div class="info">
                <a href="http://dummy_link/" target="_blank">
                <div class="sub-title">Va</div></a>
                <hr class="divider">
                <div class="cost">365</div>
                <img alt="click_here" onclick="$.hanger_click_handler()" class="span2 pull-right logo-right visible-desktop visible-tablet hang" src="/static/img/hanger.svg" data-target="http://dummy_link/">
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jquery code and I'm positive it's wrapped inside `jquery(document).ready(function(){});`

```js
$.hanger_click_handler = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("hang lcick");
}   

$('img.hang').on('click', $.hanger_click_handler);
```

I can even see this function mapped in the console using `$._data($('img.hang')[0], 'events').click[0].handler` But when I click the image I don't see anything in the console. Where am I going wrong? This was working fine before. I tried switching `<img/>` tag with `<div>` tag, but still it doesn't work. Looks like nobody else had this problem before. So bad. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE**: Ok, we found the problem. I had recently put `z-index: -1` in the style definition of `.thumbnail`. I needed that because the items were overlapping with the menu bar. Is there anyway I can resolve this z-index problem? I tried many combinations like giving the menu bar a z-index of 2000 and giving this `<ul>` tag a z-index of 2. But it hasn't worked, thus far. My understanding is that elements with higher z-index come over those with lower z-index. Any other things I need to know? And thanks for sparing time to help! SO community has helped me do amazing things till date.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: always create fiidle. :(

Comment: for the `z-index` issue, does the menu bar have `position: relative` set? Otherwise, `z-index` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/xmHxt/

You don't need both an `onclick` attribute and to wire up the event handler via jQuery (using the `.on` method). Just choose one, and prefer jQuery to putting JavaScript in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

`$('img.hang').on('click', $.hanger_click_handler);` change this to `$('body').on('click', 'img.hang', $.hanger_click_handler);`, if you are generating elements dynamically else try `$('img.hang').bind('click', $.hanger_click_handler);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and raise your performance:

HTML removing onclick

```
<ul>
<li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail item">
            <div class="image"><img src="http://dummy_link/" alt=""></div>
            <div class="info">
                <a href="http://dummy_link/" target="_blank">
                <div class="sub-title">Va</div></a>
                <hr class="divider">
                <div class="cost">365</div>
                <img alt="click_here" class="span2 pull-right logo-right visible-desktop visible-tablet hang" src="/static/img/hanger.svg" data-target="http://dummy_link/">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail item">
            <div class="image"><img src="http://dummy_link/" alt=""></div>
            <div class="info">
                <a href="http://dummy_link/" target="_blank">
                <div class="sub-title">Va</div></a>
                <hr class="divider">
                <div class="cost">365</div>
                <img alt="click_here" class="span2 pull-right logo-right visible-desktop visible-tablet hang" src="/static/img/hanger.svg" data-target="http://dummy_link/">
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
clickHandler = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
}

$('ul').find('img.hang').on('click', clickHandler);
```

Working example at:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpXz5/)